# Surjectiveness of standard-normal c.d.f.

Tags: functions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

Let $\phi:\mathbb R \to (0,1)$ be a function defined as $\phi(y)=\int_{-\infty}^y\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\dfrac {x^2}{2}}dx , \forall y\in \mathbb R$ , then is it true that $\phi$ is surjective ? If yes, then what is the proof ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Im guessing a proof can use facts that as $y\rightarrow\infty$, $\phi(y)=1$, $y\rightarrow -\infty$ $\phi(y)=0$ and that $\phi(y)$ is a strictly  increasing function

Answer (score 6):

We have $\lim_{y\to-\infty}\phi(y)=0$ and $\lim_{y\to\infty}\phi(y)=1$. Moreover, the function $\phi$ is continuous. Thus, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, the function $\phi$ is surjective.